# Shortcut to get all private field names combined with && operator as a generated line of code?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, code-templates

Is it possible to use reflection when we write a code-template?

I was just thinking if it is possible to write a piece of code-template that will return me a list of all private field in the class separated by && operator in Visual Stuudio?

Let's say, I will enter "getAllPrivates&&" (or press a shortcut key) in the VS editor and it will return me something like this:

```
private bool _privateFiel1 = false;
private bool _privateFiel2 = true;
private bool _privateFiel3 = false;
private bool _privateFiel4 = false;
private bool _privateFiel5 = true;

// Here I press the shortcut or call the code-template and get his:

_privateFiel1 && _privateFiel2  && _privateFiel3 && _privateFiel4 && _privateFiel5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not easy. The people at DevExpress I think basically implemented a compilation process to determine this. I hear the same about resharper. If you can look at using [DXCore](http://rorybecker.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-new-dxcore-plugin.html) to do the heavy lifting for you. And Since you can get a free copy of [CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) I think this will be all you need.